# How to define a function using object literal syntax?

Tags: javascript

Objects can be defined using object literal syntax like so

```
var a = {number: 3}
```

Since all functions are objects, it follows that one should also be able to define a function in this manner. However, as far as I know, there exists only three ways to define a function:

1. assigning a function expression to a variable

   `var a = function() {console.log("defined using function expression")};`
2. function declaration (statement)

   `function a() {console.log("defined using function declaration")}`
3. using the `Function` constructor

   `var b = new Function('console.log("this was constructed by Function")');`

Is there a fourth method "using object literal syntax", and if so what does it look like? If not, does this mean that functions are not real objects (in the same manner that `arguments` looks just like an array but is not really one)? How else is a function then different from real objects apart from not being able to be defined by the object literal syntax just like every other object?

Comment: Have you tried? A quick test shows that it does indeed work. `var a = {theFunction: function() {blablabla} };` So what's the problem?

Comment: You cannot define any other Objects with the object literal syntax either, not just `Function`. No `Date`, no `XMLHTTPRequest` ...

Comment: Mr Lister: I believe what you just did was define a method, not a function.

Comment: Well, anyway, your answer is no. Use a function declaration (like pattern 1 or 2 above) to declare functions, the object literal syntax to declare objects, string literals to declare Strings, integer and floating point literals to declare numbers and so forth.

Comment: Thilo: apologies for sounding pedantic, you said "the object literal syntax to declare objects" but can you clarify which objects? because functions are objects too.

Comment: "How else is a function then different from real objects" --- those are *real objects*. (not sure where you've got the term "a real object" from though). How they are different: they might be invoked.

Comment: Yes, Functions are objects, as are Dates and XMLHTTPRequests. None of those can be made via the "object literal syntax". Just plain old Objects (and maybe Arrays if you want to include their literal syntax here).

Answer (score 1):

A literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code.

With the object literal syntax you can create simple "key-value-pair" objects. That's what its made for.

You cannot create any other object types with it, but these are still objects nonetheless.